# Hausdorff dimension between $(1,2)$

Tags: fractals, hausdorff-dimension

Is there a number $c \in (1,2)$ for which there exist some interesting geometric property/properties which hold for every set of Hausdorff dimension in $(1,c)$ and does not hold for any set of Hausdorff dimension in $(c,2)$? As is stated this question is somehow vaque but I will welcome any examples of such properties, especially those which can be see ,,with the naked eye''.